# Best way to switch between multiple view controllers while preserving any downloaded data?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to have multiple UIViewControllers that can be accessed from a side menu and without having to re-download any data each time the view controller is shown?

Say for example I have three view controllers, one is a homepage that shows recent notifications, one is a news page that shows recent articles and one is a page that has a collection of images. When each view controller is loaded, data is downloaded from a remote server and displayed - if the user switches to another view controller and back again I want the previously downloaded data to be shown immediately without having to be re-downloaded (until a UIRefreshControl is used or similar).

Off the top of my head I can see this being achieved in 4 ways:

1. Store the data in a singleton and load the data from this if it has been previously downloaded, however, this seems to go against general practices that I have seen and also doesn't seem efficient - especially if there is a lot of data and/or multiple view controller.
2. Use a UITabBarController that selects the index based on the side menu instead of the traditional bottom bar, would this cause issues if there were 10-12 items on the side menu?
3. Cache the data to disk (using NSCache etc) and instantiate/dismiss each view controller as needed, the view controller can use the cached data - only one view controller will exist in memory at a time.
4. Use some kind of customised container view that caches the view controllers and loads them as they are needed, feels a bit hacky and not very efficient?

What are the best ways to achieve this? Most tutorials I see just show how to segue/present view controllers but I have struggled to find anything that explains how to preserve the data that was downloaded on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an FYI. If one of your ViewControllers is supposed to "show recent notifications/articles" then caching data won't work because it might not be the most recent unless you pull from the server every time. (Unless the recents are getting pushed and even then you might have huge sync issues if you don't pull every time.)

That said, you options 1 and 3 are effectively the same, the only difference is where you are keeping the information.

You should not be using a tab bar controller. If you can't use UISplitViewController then you should make your own custom container view controller.

As for the caching issue. I would implement some sort of caching mechanism for each endpoint. It could store in ram or on disk but I think in ram is better because the data sounds pretty volatile.

Set it up so that when a view controller makes a "network" call, the function it uses calls the closure with the last data it pulled and then optionally can make the network call again and call the closure a second time with the new data. This way the VCs will be very responsive in getting data up ASAP and still pull in the new data on every view will appear.

Comment: I like the idea of calling the closure twice, I hadn't thought of this previously and sounds exactly like what I am looking for. Is there anything wrong with caching the data in a singleton or would you suggest using something like CoreData as the other commenter suggested?

Comment: I would just cache the data for each endpoint as an independent entity in RAM. Not a singleton because nothing would even know it exists except for the function that calls the closure. So probably a private var within the API file.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a combination of option 3 and 4.

There are many formats you could use to cache the data to disk. You could use a database like CoreData or Realm, or write directly to files as a Plist, JSON, NSKeyedArchive.

You probably should build a container view controller as well. Thats what a TabBarController is after all. It's pretty easy to do and [the docs cover what you need to do](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652844). This will make you app more efficient by only having to load data from the database/file the first tome you go to the view controller. Then when switching sections, it can just show the VC thats already been loaded.

Comment: You may want to make note of the memory overhead required to keep all VCs alive and loaded.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was unsure whether a custom container was necessary but from the various comments it appears so. Are there any precautions I should take storing the VCs in memory, or just let the logic in didReceiveMemoryWarning in each VC handle any issues?

Comment: Unless you're working with lots of images or other large forms of data (multiple MB), memory usage likley wont be an issue. I'd try to avoid any [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)